# Register Certain Click events in iframe

Tags: css, html, iframe, pointer-events

I am trying to load a navigation header through an iframe so that various websites can all have the same navbar. I know there are other methods of accomplishing this (such as jQuery load) but I'd like to try and get it working with an iframe. In order to make it work, I gave the iframe a size of the whole page.

http://jsfiddle.net/7sLfq433/1/

Unfortunately, with this code it's impossible to click the items underneath the iframe. I was able to solve this by giving the iframe `pointer-events: none;`

http://jsfiddle.net/7sLfq433/2/

With this attribute though, it's impossible to use any of the nav bar actions.

Is it possible to turn off `pointer-events` for everything except the nav bar? It will be ideal if the navbar itself (https://gist.github.com/dehli/bdddc8b66151b0a87643) could be modified so that minimal changes need to be done when including the iframe.

Another option would be to give the iframe a low z-index, and modify the drop down menus so they have a higher z-index. Is is possible to modify the z-index of inner elements in an iframe?

http://jsfiddle.net/7sLfq433/4/

Comment: The problem is not the pointer event. The problem is your `iframe` is actually `absolute` with a `height: 100%` and `z-index: 1000`. So yes, the iframe takes all the page and when you click anywhere, you click the iframe, nothing else.

Comment: @RedBreast The iframe needs those attributes so that the dropdown can be visible over the rest of the page. If I gave it a smaller height or no z-index, then the dropdown wouldn't be visible.